# Unable to start nginx on Ubuntu on any port even though only port 80 is in use

Tags: python, ubuntu, nginx

I am unable to start nginx on Ubuntu16.04.

When I run `sudo /etc/init.d/nginx start`, I get an error.

```
(env) agaidis@Computer:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/nginx start
[....] Starting nginx (via systemctl): nginx.serviceJob for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
failed!
```

When I look deeper into the error message by calling,

```
sudo systemctl status nginx.service
```

I get the following feedback:

```
(env) agaidis@Computer:~/www$ sudo systemctl status nginx.service
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2017-11-29 01:03:16 EST; 1min 57s ago
  Process: 6887 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 6883 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Nov 29 01:03:13 Computer nginx[6887]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Nov 29 01:03:14 Computer nginx[6887]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Nov 29 01:03:14 Computer nginx[6887]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Nov 29 01:03:15 DComputer nginx[6887]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Nov 29 01:03:15 Computer nginx[6887]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Nov 29 01:03:16 Computer nginx[6887]: nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()
Nov 29 01:03:16 Computer systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Nov 29 01:03:16 Computer systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
Nov 29 01:03:16 Computer systemd[1]: nginx.service: Unit entered failed state.
Nov 29 01:03:16 Computer systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I have been following the steps on [this website](https://realpython.com/blog/python/kickstarting-flask-on-ubuntu-setup-and-deployment/) to get nginx and gunicorn up a running. I have been looking all over the web for fixes to my problem, but nothing is working.

I have a different server running on port 80 that isn't nginx and so I have switched the ports in my `/etc/nginx/sited-available/default`, `/etc/nginx/sited-available/<name of flask app>`, and `/etc/nginx/sited-enabled/<name of flask app>` all to listen and respond on port 8888. I have tried other port numbers as well. Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to help at all.

My `/etc/nginx/sited-available/default` file looks like so:

```
##
# You should look at the following URL's in order to grasp a solid understanding
# of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls
# http://wiki.nginx.org/QuickStart
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Configuration
#
# Generally, you will want to move this file somewhere, and start with a clean
# file but keep this around for reference. Or just disable in sites-enabled.
#
# Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
##

# Default server configuration
#
server {
    #listen 8080 default_server;
    listen [::]:8888 ipv6only=on default_server;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #   include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #   # With php7.0-cgi alone:
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #   # With php7.0-fpm:
    #   fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #   deny all;
    #}
}


# Virtual Host configuration for example.com
#
# You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
# to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
#
#server {
#   listen 80;
#   listen [::]:80;
#
#   server_name example.com;
#
#   root /var/www/example.com;
#   index index.html;
#
#   location / {
#       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#   }
#}
```

My `/etc/nginx/sited-enabled/<name of flask app>` and `/etc/nginx/sited-available/<name of flask app>` files look like so:

```
server {
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8888;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
    location /static {
        alias /home/agaidis/www/<name of flask app>/static/;
    }
}
```

Some other things I have tried include `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade nginx` before I try to start the server.

Is there anyway to fix the problem without stopping the current server running on port 80? Any and all help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Can you post the contents of /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default. Also try to start nginx as a service `sudo service nginx restart`

Comment: When I run `sudo service nginx restart` I get the following error: `Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.` I will edit my post above to include all of `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default`.

Comment: Also what is the version of nginx that you are running?

Comment: The default file is posted above. I am running `nginx version: nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)`

Comment: Can you try setting `ipv6only=off` or add another line saying `listen 8888` above the listen line?

Comment: I added `listen 8080;` and
        `listen [::]:8888 ipv6only=off default_server;` Still does not work. I also tried the different combinations of those modes.

Comment: If you do not specifically set the `listen` directive then it will default to port 80. So your flask app server block is trying to run on port 80.

Comment: I set the port # to 8888 on my flask app and added the `listen 8080;` to my sites-available/<name of flast app> file and it still doesn't allow me to run nginx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added `listen 8080;` to the top of my `/etc/nginx/sited-available/<name of flask app>` file. Thus, it became:

```
server {

    listen 8080;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8888;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
    location /static {
        alias /home/agaidis/www/<name of flask app>/static/;
    }
}
```

That fixed my problem.